# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46

Tags: magento-1.8, onepage-checkout, paypal, payment, payment-methods

I’m trying **onepage checkout**. When I'm exiting **2co payment page** by clicking on **Place order button** I'm navigating back to my site and the URL looks like this.

https://www.example.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/

and I got an error on the page as shown below

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in /home/xxx/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46

I have no idea and PHP knowledge to fix it.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you done any customization, or added any checkout related extension?

Comment: No use any checkout related extension for this site.

Comment: Try disabling your other extensions one by one and check if it still exists

Comment: Reinstall or upgrade your payment module.

Answer (score 4):

Even with very little PHP knowledge, you can always diagnose issues thanks to Magento's error reporting mechanism.

This error indicates the exact file & line of code which are responsible for it, so take the following steps:

1. Navigate through `app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/` & open `Observer.php`,
2. Scroll to line 46

The line of code in 1.7 reads as follows:

```
if ($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() != 'free') {
```

Now, the error message also tells you that the following code is what is causing the issue:

```
Call to a member function getMethodInstance()
```

So after you read the line of code on line 46, you'll see that that method is applied to the `$order` object, this is defined just above line 46 (on line 44):

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

Now, knowing PHP you'd know that if the event did not catch the order correctly, the error would have been thrown here, I.E. on line 44, but it wasn't which means that it was caught correctly.

THUS, you can establish that the issue is with your payment method, because `$order->getPayment()` is a `non object` according to the error message.

You're likely using a modified payment method of some sorts which needs to be diagnosed.

Comment: So, how to get payment code?

Answer (score 4):

Please check if the payment module redirects you to an insecure page (http://).

If you're using https in the checkout and the module redirects to a non-secure redirect page, Magento will throw you this error.

Answer (score 4):

If order is loaded by `loadByIncrementId($orderId)` and orderId is not valid, `$order->save()` will then cause this exact error. Check anywhere in code where an order is being saved, thus causing the function `salesOrderBeforeSave` to run in the file the error indicates, breaking at `$order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are doing something like this:

`$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(300000112);`

i.e trying to load order with increment id. Instead use this:

`$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(300000112);`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with a gateway and resolve it. Review the documentation of payment gateway about the response variables naming. Must be the same with your OK/NOT OK page

Answer (score 1):

Go to system >configuration >advanced >advanced just enable and save your payment method